# How to display a table of data on clicking a slice of google pi chart?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, google-visualization

I am new to google visualization and codeigniter. i made a pie chart and i want to display table with the some data on clicking the slices,
How can i do it?

This is the function in javascript to display the pi-chart:

```
     <script>
     function drawChart() 
     {
  `
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['User', 'No of Groups'],
      <?php foreach($t->result() as $tsk)
     { ?>['<?php  echo $tsk->status ?>', <?php echo  $tsk->count ?> ],
      <?php 
      } ?> ]); 
    var options = {
        // pieSliceText: 'label',
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      colors: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']

    };

   var chart = new 
   google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

when i click on a slice i want to display a table with details of that corresponding slice (i,e status) .

Please help me

Comment: use the `'select'` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#events) on the pie chart, to know when a slice is selected ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38872712/5090771)), then draw the table chart, the same way you draw the pie chart -- be sure to add the `'table'` package to the `load` statement...

Comment: i dont want a table chart, i just want to display a table of contents when i click on a slice of pie chart .i used 'select'  like this: Inside the function drawChart i added **'google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', onAreaSliceSelected);'** and after the function **'function onAreaSliceSelected(){
  var sel = pieChart.getSelection(); 
  alert('you selected '+sel); 
}' **

Comment: the 'select ' event is working. i reffered [This](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity).But in the 'selectHandler function ' i want to draw an html table.Can you help?And thankyou for the response

Comment: google's table chart __is__ an html table, regardless, if you just want to draw an html table, there should be plenty of examples, 3 [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775575/5090771)...